# How to show an input field on node view, not just on node edit / add?

Tags: nodes, forms

I would like to show an input text area field with filtered html on node view (not on node/add !).

(I would like to show editable text in a tinymce editor here http://proofreadbot.com/proofreading/132)

What would be the easiest way of achieving this? Is there a contrib module perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webform: http://drupal.org/project/webform

Just install the module and add it as a block on the node that you want. It will be displayed on node view.

Create a Webform

Select the Webform tab

Select the Forms settings tab

Select Advanced settings

Switch on Available as block

Configure the block to be displayed on the node that you want

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to work with the existing field value in the node. So, this text field already exists.